# Embed JGraph in JFrame with YAML

Tags: swing, graph, jframe, yaml

I'm starting to create a GUI with [javabuilders](http://code.google.com/p/javabuilders/) in order to get more familiar with YAML and to implement some ideas.

Normally (in my experience) JGraph gets embedded into a standard JFrame, holding a certain object (where HelloWord() is the object with the vertexes and edges). That is very concise at [this point](http://www.jgraph.com/doc/mxgraph/index_javavis.html#2.2):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorld frame = new HelloWorld();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 320);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

I don't get the javabuilders documentation at the JFrame section (5.12, page 38, [pdf](http://javabuilders.googlecode.com/files/SwingJavaBuilder-1.1.pdf)): how can I declare an embedded JFrame and access it to hold the custom JGraph stuff?

In YAML you can easily declare a JFrame of course:

```
JFrame(name=frame, title=frame.title, size=packed, defaultCloseOperation=exitOnClose):
```

But it doesn't say where I can stack a JFrame into another JFrame and access it imho. I want to build some components around the graph. I guess there's an easy way to do that... at least I'd be happy to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `JFrame` is a [top-level container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html), you *cannot* add one to another; but you *can* add a `com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent` that holds your `com.mxgraph.view.mxGraph`. As `mxGraphComponent` extends `javax.swing.JScrollPane`, see `§5.14 JScrollPane`.